SDL compiling error using g++ undefined reference to "class::funciton"
I am getting
C:/M/B/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexewin.c:67:(.text.startup+0xbd): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: Main] Error 1

and a few
 undefined reference to Game::init(char const*, int, int, int, int, bool)'

(And for other functions as well)
Game.hpp
#pragma once

#include "src/include/SDL2/SDL.h"
#include <iostream>

class Game {

public:
    Game();
    ~Game();

    void init(const char *title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen);

    void update();
    void render();
    void clean();
    void handleEvents();

    bool running(){
        return isRunning;
    }

private:
    bool isRunning;
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;

};


Game.cpp
#include "Game.hpp"

Game::Game()
{}

Game::~Game()
{}

void Game::init(const char *title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen)
{
    int flags = 0;

    if(fullscreen)
    {
        flags = SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;
    }

    if(!SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)){
        std::cout << "ur in ma boy\n";

        window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xpos, ypos, width, height, flags);

        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

        if(renderer){
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 150, 150, 150, 255);
        }

        isRunning = true;
    } else {
        isRunning = false;
    }
}

void Game::handleEvents()
{
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);

    switch (event.type){
        case SDL_QUIT:
            isRunning = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void Game::update()
{}

void Game::render()
{
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void Game::clean()
{
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_Quit();
}

and Main.cpp
#include "Game.hpp"

Game *game = nullptr;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    game = new Game();

    game -> init("Window title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, 0);

    while(game -> running())
    {
        game -> handleEvents();
        game -> update();
        game -> render();
    }

    game -> clean();

    return 0;
}

I also use makefile to compile main.cpp
all:
    g++ -I src/include -L src/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2


You forgot to include game.cpp when you compiled. You need to list all your cpp files when you compile a program.

The formating in the body is a little messed up

Oh let me try that

IIRC you shouldn't need to explicitly link with mingw32. And the order of the libraries you link with is significant, try changing the order of the two SDL2 libraries.

So i tired g++ -I src/include -L src/lib -o main main.cpp Game.cpp "-lSDL", "-lSDLmain",  "-mwindows" but I am getting the same error

Are you using SDL or SDL2?  Is SDL2main (or SDLmain) needed, since you are providing a main?

i just realized that it got confused since i checked some other stack overflow questions but I am using sdl2 and it was sdl2 in the original line. To be frank with you I do not know what is needed or not because I am a complete beginner and was following a tutorial.

@Someprogrammerdude You do need -lmingw32 for SDL2. (It has something to do with linking order, IIRC because -lSDL2main provides its own main or WinMain, and -lmingw32 doesn't find it with default link order.)

I have a SDL troubleshooting guide here: How do I use SDL2 in my programs correctly?. But honestly, I'd just reinstall mingw and sdl2 from msys2, then run pkgconf --libs --cflags SDL2 to obtain the right compiler flags. This rules out any incompatibilities between the compiler and the specific library binary you got.
